# Can't create connection using CQErl (Erlang-Cassandra driver)

Tags: cassandra, erlang, erlang-shell

I'm trying to connect to Cassandra from Erlang shell using Cqerl. I use `{ok, Client} = cqerl:get_client({}).` to create connection, as stated in the documentation.
Then, the following error occurs.

```
** exception error: bad argument
 in function  ets:lookup/2
    called as ets:lookup(cqerl_client_tables,
                         {{{127,0,0,1},9042},[{keyspace,undefined}]})
 in call from cqerl_hash:get_table/1
```

is there any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the problem is that there is no 'cqerl_client_tables' ets table.
Please make sure you've started the application:

```
application:start(cqerl)
```

Comment: wow, you're right. how come I didn't realize. thanks for the answer